# Undo button within a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UIActionsheet with several buttons setup. How would I go about adding a undo function?  I'm using UITextfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the appropriate UIActionSheet button to call the `undo` method on the desired UITextField's `NSUndoManager` object. For all UITextField and UITextView objects in iOS 3.0 and higher, there is an `undoManager` object that can be accessed and used to manage undoing and redoing of operations. The necessary code would go something like this:

(UIActionSheetDelegate method implementation)

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == /*undo index*/)
        [yourTextField.undoManager undo];
}
```

EDIT: I suggest you look at the [Apple documentation for Undo Managers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/UndoManager.html), it should help you further with this should you need it.

Comment: I have everything setup with the button index, I'm still having problems getting this thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Shake to Undo? An Undo alert comes up if you enter some text in a `UITextField`/`UITextView` & shake your iPhone.

Comment: I have. I would like to add the undo in the UIActionsheet. I have everyting setup within the UIActionsheet except the Undo button. Any code ideas for the undo button?